# 'Argument expression is not valid' when creating anonymous types dynamically

Tags: linq, expression-trees, typebuilder

I'm creating an expression tree builder to return custom anonymous types. I tried it first with discrete types and it works ok, but using TypeBuilder to build types at runtime and pass that type to the expression tree fail with this error

```
'Argument expression is not valid'
```

here is the code I use:

this method I use to create the anonymous type

```
private Type CreateAnonymousType(Dictionary<string, Type> properties)
    {
      AssemblyName dynamicAssemblyName = new AssemblyName("MyAssembly");
      AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
      ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyAssembly");

      TypeBuilder dynamicAnonymousType = dynamicModule.DefineType("ReturnType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass);
      foreach (var p in properties)
      {
        dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField(p.Key, p.Value, FieldAttributes.Public);
      }

      return dynamicAnonymousType.CreateType();
    }
```

and here is how I create the expression tree

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        cars.Add(new Car { Id = i, Name = "Car " + i, Age = 2010 + i });
      }


      IQueryable<Car> allCars = cars.AsQueryable();

      var properties = new Dictionary<string, Type>
      {
        { "Id", typeof(int) },
        { "Name", typeof(string) }
      };

      ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car), "x");
      var listMembers = properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(x, p.Key));

      var returnType = CreateAnonymousType(properties);
      object destObject = Activator.CreateInstance(returnType);


      var listBind = listMembers.Select(p => Expression.Bind(returnType.GetField(p.Member.Name), p));

      var result = Expression.New(returnType);
      var initExp = Expression.MemberInit(result, listBind.ToArray());


      var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select",
          new Type[] {
            typeof(Car),
            returnType
        }
        , Expression.Constant(allCars)
        , Expression.Lambda(initExp, x));

      var qResult = allCars.Provider.CreateQuery<IdName>(call);

      foreach (var car in qResult)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(car.Id + " - " + car.Name);
      }
```

the error happened while CreateQuery method executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `call` returns dynamically created `ReturnType` not `IdName` thus the exception. Additionally you cannot put such dynamic types like `ReturnType` as generic type parameters because compiler knows nothing about them so you should use `dynamic` instead so the type will be resolved at runtime:

```
var qResult = allCars.Provider.CreateQuery<dynamic>(call);
```